# 'Keep him good company'

Tags: american-english

> Men, one last thing before we go, we have a technician who will join us today for this mission. You know him well, his name is George Ovechkin, he's a nuclear engineer. I hope you will keep him in good company. That's all for the mission briefing. Let's head out to the battlefield!

Isn't the expression 'keep him in good company' only used when the person that's referred by 'him' is relatively new? It sounds odd if you say it to someone who is often seen hanging out with the people to whom this is said.

Please feel free to correct any mistake I've made while writing this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to be or keep** in good company**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in+good+company) idiom

> if you are in good company, other people, often respected people, are
>   in the same situation as you.

Your question:

> Isn't the expression 'keep him in good company' only used when the
>   person that's referred by 'him' is relatively new?

Not necessarily. In your example the nuclear engineer is well known, and the mission will likely need his expertise. So keep him close, (in your good company) protected, and use his expertise!

Again literary license and the context can suggest the importance of the engineer to the mission, whether he is a newcomer or a veteran.  The commanding officers use of **hope** is more like a command.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an error for "keep him good company" - to provide friendly and helpful companionship. "In good company" and "in bad company" are idioms meaning associating with good and bad people respectively.